# Как правильно составить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Добрый вечер всем!
Нужно написать регулярное выражение которое из файла выбирает строку и следующие за ней строки, до следующего ключа

Например в файле очень много ключей различных описывается :

```
/P    Вывод запросов перед созданием каждого нового файла.
/S    Копирование только непустых каталогов с подкаталогами.
/E    Копирование каталогов с подкаталогами, включая пустые.
      Эквивалентен сочетанию ключей /S /E. Совместим с ключом/T.
/C    Продолжение копирования вне зависимости от наличия ошибок.
```

Я в консоли использую команду `FINDSTR /C: "/E " file.txt > lab.txt`

при такой записи в файл выведется следующая строка :

```
/E   Копирование каталогов с подкаталогами, включая пустые.
```

а мне нужно чтобы вывелось :

```
/E   Копирование каталогов с подкаталогами, включая пустые.
     Эквивалентен сочетанию ключей /S /E. Совместим с ключом/T.
```

т.е чтобы вывелось 2 строки а если их 3 в ключе описывается то 3 .

Вопрос : как изменить регулярное выражение? ключ команды измениться на `FINDSTR /R "регулярное выражение" file.txt > file2.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FINDSTR` не умеет искать многострочные совпадения (если только не обращаться к [тёмным хакам](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773526/4267982)). Можно было бы воспользоваться [`JREPL.bat`](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), но, по-моему, он не дружит с русским языком. Так что могу посоветовать `pcregrep` (есть порт и под Windows):

```
pcre2grep -M "^/E .+(\r?\n .+)*" file.txt
```

Comment: скачал grep.exe , закинул его в System32 ,запускаю консоль, захожу в директорию где находиться мой файл , прописываю  grep -M "^/E .+(\r?\n .+)*" file.txt > text.txt, но в файл он ничего не отправляет , файл пустой

Comment: там нужно учитывать что перед ключом /E два пробела есть

Comment: большое спасибо , благодаря вам получилось вывести ,я сделал вот так grep -A 1 "/E  " file.txt > text.txt , где -A 1 это количество строк после найденной строки которые нужно вывести